# Network File Sharing no longer working after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, home-networking, file-sharing

Recently my family and I have been having problems with the Network File Sharing feature on Windows. We've had it working ever since we got our first version of Windows XP, but it seems to be troubling us now. Whenever I go into "Network", I can view all of the other computers connected to our network. I can access one of the computers but not the other. We've all turned off "Password Protected Sharing", yet it is still asking for the account credentials whenever I try and connect to my stepdad's computer. I've read that the account credentials mechanism has changed on Windows 10, but I cannot manage to work it. When I try to go to "Network" on the other PCs... Well, that's where I go blank. They cannot view my computer, yet I can view theirs. We're all connected to the same network with the exact same settings. Everything should be fine. I'm really not sure how to work this new system. :/

EDIT: I managed to connect to my stepdad's PC using `computername\accountname`,
but they cannot view any computers now. Windows File Sharing in a nutshell.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you are connecting and what resources you are connecting to? If you have file shares on the computer your are connecting to it should be as simple as %computername%\share. If you use 'map network drive', check use alternate credentials and then enter the credentials for an active account on the computer you are connecting to.